# Local host ip address

Tags: php, dart, localhost, ip

i am currently developing a simple app that use a local storage as you can see in my code this is my ip-address in the laptop, after i export the app into apk and install it in my phone i cant access the local storage as the phone have different ip-address, this is my first time doing it, can you guys help me how i can make the ip-address based on the device on the network? This is my code for the base url. Thank you.

```
const String baseurl = "http://192.xxx.xx.xxx/todos/";
```

i've filtered the ip for my safety

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by accessing the built-in variable `$_SERVER`. The server argument that you are looking for is that of the connected client, which can be accessed with the following syntax:

```php
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

More information about Server and execution environment information can be found in the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).